# What is the purpose of ammonium chloride in anti hydrogenation of alkynes?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, hydrocarbons, organic-reduction

In my organic chemistry textbook, lithium is used to create a free radical of the alkynes, to then allow the anti addition of hydrogen to get an alkene.

"The Dissolving Metal Reduction of Alkynes" is a reaction that then uses $\ce{NH4Cl}$. Why put $\ce{NH4Cl}$?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I know that in the [Birch reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birch_reduction) there is an alcohol (usually t-butanol) added to protonate the radical anion and allow the reaction to proceed, the ammonia solvent isn't sufficiently acidic to do that.  I don't think you need to do that for alkynes.  As far as I know the ammonium chloride is to quench excess sodium at the end of the reaction.

Comment: @AbelFriedman maybe jerepierre's answer is plausible?

Comment: @yolo123: Completely agree.

Comment: What about quenching sodium?

Comment: Hmm, do you think that NH4Cl could be added for a reason relating to the reactivity of the double bond formed? (I know double bonds can be quite reactive sometimes, that's why I'm asking.)

Comment: I think the ammonium chloride is used to protonated the amide ion. Protonation generates ammonia, which can easily be evaporated away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Products from reaction step (1) are the *trans*-alkene and 2 equivalents of the amide $\ce{LiNHEt}$, a strong base. Step (2) is the workup of the reaction mixture with aqueous $\ce{NH4Cl}$ solution, which serves several purposes. First, it quenches the lithium amide and unreacted lithium metal.

$$\ce{LiNHEt + NH4Cl ->~ EtNH2 + NH3 + LiCl}$$
$$\ce{Li + H2O ->~ LiOH (aq) + \frac{1}{2} H2\uparrow}$$

Secondly, the *trans*-alkene is usually less water-soluble than ethyl amine and the lithium and ammonium salts, and can be separated from the workup mixture by precipitation or extraction with an organic solvent.